# jQuery not returning number from an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok so I'm having a bit of trouble returning a number from an html tag using jquery.

So lets say i have this: `<p class="number">4,500.50</p>` and i want to get the number from this tag using jquery, so I have the following.

```
var number = parseFloat($('.number').html());
```

But this only returns the number `4` instead of the full number. I also treied with the `.text()` method but the result is the same. Any ideas as to how to resolve this? Any help is appreciated.

Example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zf1ctums/1/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string has a non standard (well probably in certain contries people are used to it) format. parseFloat only knows about digits and decimal POINT. So you need to delete the commas:

```
var number = parseFloat($('.number').html().replace(',', ''));
```

Comment: [JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/zf1ctums/2/), which is pretty much the same in theory, though organised a little differently. You should, however, explain *why* this works rather than just posting code. Without teaching the OP, or future visitors to this question, anything from which they can learn there's little point posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks this solved it. From what I just saw in the other question and understand, javascript stops looking for more numbers after the "," and only considers the "4" part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the number should be `4500,50`.
You should not pass the thousand separator.

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).